# How to initialize a nested object in Dart. NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'user'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting a `NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'user'` error when I execute the following. I assume I'm missing a constructor or setter or initializing wrong.

```
class Mac{
  MacUser user;

  Mac({
    this.user
  });
}

class MacUser{
  String username;
  String password;

  MacUser({
    this.username, 
    this.password,
  });
}

void main(){
  Mac mac;
  mac.user.username = "root"; // NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'user'
  mac.user.password = "root";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to set the property on a null object. You need to define some value first before changing:

Example:

```
Mac mac = new Mac(user: MacUser(username: "username", password: "password")); // initialize some value first

  mac.user.username = "root";
  mac.user.password = "root";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Mac mac =  new Mac(user: new MacUser()); // this line will Create a Null Object as you may or may not have both values at this time later on you can edit those value by below code
mac.user.username = "root";
mac.user.password = "root";
```

Comment: still, MacUser will be null, You need to initialize MacUser too.

  ``Mac mac = new Mac(user: new MacUser());``

Comment: you can try yourself brother and let me know :)

Comment: yup., there was a big mistake thanks, Updated the Code. Thanks